# How do I disable echo from Mac terminal programmatically using GoLang

Tags: macos, go, terminal, echo

I am trying to disable echo from my Mac terminal using GoLang. I tried using

```
exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "-echo").Run()
```

It works for linux terminal but it doesn't work for Mac and Windows. In Mac, in bash and zsh, I manually tried to use

```
stty -echo
stty -echoctl
```

Both didn't work.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: does stty work as intended on mac and windows as issued directly on terminal ?  without using golang ?

Comment: @ScottStensland .. no, stty -echo doesn't work directly on terminal. Is there some settings we need to change?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer the question of why your example does not work, here is how one could read the secret from a terminal without echoing it back (here is a link to the signature and documentation - [link](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal#ReadPassword)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Your password: ")
    bytepw, err := terminal.ReadPassword(int(syscall.Stdin))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("Your password was '%s'\n", string(bytepw))
}
```

Expected output:

```
mac:~ jabbson$ go run testpass.go
Your password:

Your password was 'mypass'
mac:~ jabbson$
```